# Advice on CPU internal heat spreader maintenance

Tags: central-processing-unit, dell-poweredge

I would like to ask if it is advisable to remove the external heat spreader of server CPUs, clean off the factory grease between the insides of the external spreader and the internal heat spreader (IHS) and reapply from new.

I ask this as I have a couple of poweredge servers that are going in for scheduled maintenance and cleaning featuring dual quad CPUs (Intel Xeon E5335). Since 2007, they never had the IHS grease replaced. Only the grease between the external cpu external heat spreader and the cooler was changed regularly.

I can only image how burnt-in the grease is on the IHS after all these years of constant operation.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that these CPU's are running hotter than when first acquired, or are you asking for another reason, e.g. preventive maintenance?

Comment: Our climate is hot, so we are accustomed to check temperatures and maximise cooling efficiency. I have inherited these 9th generation poweredge servers and do not have the possibility to compare temperature readings since the initial commissioning and `lm-sensors` on Ubuntu 16.04 is not that accurate. But I think the cpus are hotter as the fans are revving up all the more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With aging, thermal grease tends to lose some of its head-conduction performance.

This means that replacing the thermal paste/grease can be a good idea but, as modern sockets/CPUs are somewhat fragile, I would do this only if the system show signs of overheating.

In other words: if your CPUs are overheating, replace the thermal paste. If not, don't bother.

EDIT: if you are speaking of the **internal** grease used between the CPU die and the integrated heat spreader, do **not** do anything: delidding a CPU is a very dangerous task, not worth for production machines

Comment: As per my comment above, I think that the efficiency of the internal heat spreader is not 100% as the fans are revving up. Idling speed has raised from 6000 rpm to 7500 to keep an internal chassis temperature of 22%. Honestly I am a bit hesitant to open the CPUs as have no idea which black epoxy I should use to seal the heat spreader back on the pcb.

Comment: You should watch at your CPU temp. Is it too high?

Comment: I've edited my reply, give it a look.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I would not go that far, I was referring to the grease that sits between the top of elongated internal heat spreader and the inside of the external cpu heat spreader. What is your opinion on just these. Still though I would need to get hold of the black epoxy that seals the external heat spreader with the die.

Comment: As stated above, if you CPU is overheating, replace the thermal paste. If not, don't do that. Anyway, the *CPU die* is the internal silicon *under* the integrated heat spreader.